# How to determine which way the mouse is being dragged (Win32, C++)

Tags: c++, winapi

I am currently working on a project which requires me to know when the mouse is being dragged to the left, or to the right.

What I would like to do with this information, is drag an object in 3d space (with OpenGL/Win32), left, or right, depending on which way the mouse was dragged.

The problem is, I have no idea how to determine which way the mouse is being dragged.

I tried finding the previous x coordinate, and subtracting it from the current x coordinate, but I do not know how to determine the previous x coordinate!

Can someone please help me?

(**P.S.** I already know that the current x mouse location is found with LOWORD(lParam), but what I do not know is how to determine the previous x mouse location. Thanks for your time.)

Comment: You could store the current position in a variable and use that next time as the previous position.

Comment: I have tried the above method, however, my problem is, when I store the current position, and check it against the new current position, they always wind up being equal(the same). For example, if my current mouse position is 10, and I changed it again, I would check xprev against curx, and they would both equal 10.

Comment: A static variable in the windows procedure would be just fine for storing the previous variable. The heart of the solution is to make the variable that stores the previous x position be global to the function itself.

Comment: @JamesDiaz: "*when I store the current position, and check it against the new current position, they always wind up being equal*" Then your code has a bug in it. Maybe you should post the code so that we could see it.

Answer (score 3):

You could do it yourself by storing the current mouse position as the 'last' mouse position, and then after two mouse position updates, subtract.

```
onMouseMove(mouseX, mouseY):
    if previousX and previousY are set:
        deltaX = previousX - mouseX
        deltaY = previousY - mouseY
        actOnDrag(deltaX, deltaY)

    previousX = mouseX
    previousY = mouseY
```

You could set `previousX` and `previousY` to some crazy sentinel value (e.g. -1) to determine whether they have ever been set.

Comment: Two questions, how do I determine when the mouse has been updated twice, and second, what is this "actOnDrag" I was totally lost at that point.

Comment: @JamesDiaz: "*what is this "actOnDrag" I was totally lost at that point.*" That's the function *you write* to do what you want based on the direction the mouse is being dragged in. What are you talking about with the mouse being "updated twice?"

Comment: Ravuya wrote: "and then after two mosue position updates, subtract." I would like to know how to determine exactly when the mouse position has been updated twice. (That's what I meant by updated twice)..

Comment: @JamesDiaz: The last line of his post tells you how.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `DragDetect` function.

```
BOOL DragDetect(HWND  hwnd, POINT pt);
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-dragdetect